# How to send an email to a user programatically? (OpenERP & Python)

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

In my OpenERP modules I occasionally need to send notifications or messages to my users, but the obvious way (to me, at least) of using `res.users.message_post` put a message on the users record instead of sending the message to the user.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can send messages you need to have the `Social Network` module installed (it lives in `.../addons/mail` if you want to see its code).

After that, the following snippet will do the job:

```
from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID

def send_message(oe, cr, user_ids, subject, body):
    "sends message to user_ids"
    mail_message = oe.pool.get('mail.message')
    mail_message_subtype = oe.pool.get('mail.message.subtype')
    [discussion_id] = mail_message_subtype.browse(
            cr, SUPERUSER_ID, [('name','=','Discussions')]
            )
    users = oe.pool.get('res.users').search(cr, uid, user_ids)
    mail_message.create(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, values=dict(
            type='email',
            subtype_id=discussion.id,
            partner_ids=[(4, u.partner_id.id) for u in users],
            subject=subject,
            body=body,
            ))
```

Stuff this in a utility module somewhere and you're good to go.

A couple comments:

- When calling, pass `self` as the first parameter
      `send_message(self, cr, ...)`
- if you want to make this a method of a class instead, just replace the `oe`'s with `self`, and omit `self` from the parameters
- This will send a message inside OpenERP to the users and, if any user has his/her preferences set up to forward to external email, an actual email will be generated for them.